# How to send the data using react js to another page?

Tags: javascript, php, dom, reactjs

I have `index.html`. In that I have form which accepts some data.After clicking on submit button, I want to send the all data to the `process.php` file in ajax format using react js. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There are no AJAX utilities bundled with React, but you can use the native `XMLHttpRequest` object or any external library that wraps it in a more user-friendly API.

Comment: I recommend https://github.com/github/fetch

Answer (score 0):

**Correct way** :
There is no AJAX functionality in the Reactjs. Basically react is just a view layer. For use of Network layer and Data layer you have to use some other configuration with React . Best will be Reactjs + Flux like facebook.

I like fluxxor for fluxx + react combination. fluxxor provides actions . By using those action you can call some external API.

**Or Hack :**

```
var Form = React.createClass({
    submit:function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     // make ajax call . 
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <form onsubmit = {this.submit} > </form>
        );
    }

});
```